# Interface doesn't declare that it throws, yet documentation says it can throw

Tags: java, exception

(and it does indeed throw)

In my experience with Java, if you are throwing an `Exception` in a method of a class that implements an interface, then the method you are overriding on the interface must also declare that it throws the `Exception`.

For example, consider the following minimal example:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void doSomething() throws IOException;
}


public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

However, I noticed that java.nio's [`ByteBuffer.get()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/nio/ByteBuffer.java#ByteBuffer.get%28%29) doesn't declare that it throws any exceptions:

```
public abstract byte get();
```

But, its documentation says the following:

```
Throws:
    BufferUnderflowException If the buffer's current position is not smaller than its limit
```

I then checked the implementation of [`HeapByteBuffer.get()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/nio/HeapByteBuffer.java#HeapByteBuffer.get%28%29):

```
public byte get() {
    return hb[ix(nextGetIndex())];
}
```

There we find [`nextGetIndex()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/nio/Buffer.java#Buffer.nextGetIndex%28%29) which is actually the method that would throw the `BufferUnderflowException`, which by the way, also isn't declared with `throws BufferUnderflowException`:

```
final int nextGetIndex() {                          // package-private
    if (position >= limit)
        throw new BufferUnderflowException();
    return position++;
}
```

#### Question

So, what am I missing here? If I try to declare a method that throws an `Exception`, I get the error

```
Unhandled exception type Exception
```

Is this an IDE only error? I'm using Eclipse Juno. I would think if it was IDE only it would be a warning, but it is an actual error.

How can ByteBuffer.get() not declare its interface with `throw BufferUnderflowException`, yet throw (and not catch it) one at the same time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only need to declare Checked Exception to be thrown in method, but not the Unchecked one. `BufferUnderflowException` is an unchecked exception (it extends `RuntimeException`), so it doesn't need to be declared to be thrown, and neither it needs to be handled.

**Reference:**

- [JLS - Kinds and Causes of Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1)

Comment: More specifically, you are required to declare anything that extends `Throwable` unless it extends `Error` or `RuntimeException` directly or indirectly.

Comment: Here I thought Exceptions were a simple thing. Looks like I have a lot to learn about Exceptions. Thanks for the point in the right direction.

Comment: @crush. You're welcome. You can search for exception hierarchy in Java :)